# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars for encrypted data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scalar

I'm trying to encrypt this dataset [Wholesales customer](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wholesale+customers), having dropped the first two columns (Channel and Region).
The encryption script works fine, as I'm able to generate the public key for encryption. However, I think the problem is with the nested for loop lines. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from Paillier_CRT.gmpy2mod import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


priv, pub = generate_keypair(128)
n = pub.n
print("The public key is:", n)


def to_encrypt(public, data_matrix):
    data_encrypted = encrypt(public, data_matrix)
    return data_encrypted


def load_data():
    raw_data = pd.read_csv('wholesales1.csv')
    dtset = raw_data.drop(['Channel'], axis=1)
    new_dtset = dtset.drop(['Region'], axis=1)
    converted_data = new_dtset.values
    data_to_encrypt = []

    for row in converted_data:
        for elem in row:
            data_to_encrypt = to_encrypt(pub, int(converted_data))
            return data_to_encrypt


working_data = load_data()
print("The encrypted data is: ", working_data)
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually means that you are using a scalar value where an array was expected.

Instead of

```
data_to_encrypt = to_encrypt(pub, int(converted_data))
```

you can try

```
data_to_encrypt = to_encrypt(pub, converted_data.astype(int))
```